# How install variable inspector in Jupyterlab >= 4.0?

Tags: variables, jupyter-lab, inspector

Is there a way to install inspector variable in Jupyterlab >=4.0?

I tried installing inspector variable extensions in Jupyterlab 4.0.2 but an incompatible message is shown during installation and only with Jupyterlab >=3.x and <4.x is supported.